# How to insert HTML ASCII art from document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At the moment i'm trying to read .txt files which could contain ASCII arts and display them in my HTML document with JQuery. Simple text is displayed right but i have formatting problems with the arts.

[image]
[image]

How can i fix this ?

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    $.get('/test/posts/header.txt', function(data) {

    var lines = data.split('\n');

    for (var i = 0, len = lines.length; i < len; i++) {

    $(".stream").append('<div class="line"><p class="header">' + lines[i] + '</p></div>');
    }

  });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the excess spaces are getting stripped. Either you replace all the spaces with `&nbsp` in every line with simple `... + lines[i].replace(/ /g,'&nbsp') + ...`, or you wrap everything in `<pre>...</pre>`:

```
'<div class="line"><p class="header"><pre>' + lines[i] + '</pre></p></div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<pre id="asciiart"></pre>
```

I see you are using jquery:

```
$("#asciiart" ).load( "/test/posts/header.txt" );
```

You can also use css

```
.line{
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

or in your case

```
<div class="line"><p class="header"></div></div>

.line>.header
```

I think that's right.

Good Luck